# Part of my image disappears when I click on it

Tags: jquery, html, image, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

This site is based on a jquery accordion. When I click on the first link in the accordion (Chirp...), part of the little bird image disappears for a second then reappears. Do you have any idea why?

http://imip.rvadv.com/index2.html#home

Comment: I think it would be even nicer to keep the whole section and bird sitting still. The text "Chirp. Would you like to..." does not really need to move.

Comment: I agree. I just don't know what I'm doing! LOL. I just found this accordion js and I'm trying to implement it the best I can...I guess that question will show up on here soon enough! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's disappearing because the animation is applying an `overflow: hidden;` to the containers that it's animating.

Give me a sec and I'll see if I can find a fix for you.

```
...
```

<strike>Ok, the way that I'd fix it is to have the bird image as a background on `#wrapper`</strike>

Thought of a better way.

Change the width of `#wrapper` to `920px` and add left and right padding to your accordion `li` items of `30px` (half of the 60px that we've added to the total width). This way your bird image will be contained within the `li` and thus not hidden by the overflow cutting it off on animation.

Note: the animation is a little off, there's some weird jumpy-ness going on, but I've ignored that for the purposes of this and just looked at how to make the bird image not get cut-off.

`:)`

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to address the jumpiness later.